# Matlab Attempt to reference field of non-structure array

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have 3 figures

1- principle contain 2 buttons

2- figure to load one image and diplay it on an axe

3- figure to load two images and diplay it on axes

when i run the figure 3 or 2 all alone everything is fine and the images got displayed.

**THE PROBLEM** when i run the prgrm from principle.fig and open the 2nd figure or the 3rd an error popup

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in untitled3>pere_Callback (line 91)
axes(handles.axes1);
```

my code

```
    function varargout = untitled3(varargin)
% UNTITLED3 MATLAB code for untitled3.fig
%      UNTITLED3, by itself, creates a new UNTITLED3 or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = UNTITLED3 returns the handle to a new UNTITLED3 or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      UNTITLED3('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in UNTITLED3.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      UNTITLED3('Property','Value',...) creates a new UNTITLED3 or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before untitled3_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to untitled3_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help untitled3

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 01-May-2017 17:19:08

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @untitled3_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @untitled3_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before untitled3 is made visible.
function untitled3_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to untitled3 (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for untitled3
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes untitled3 wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = untitled3_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pere.
function pere_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pere (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global im im2
[path,user_conce] = imgetfile();
if user_conce
    sprintf('error');
    return
end
im=imread(path);
im2 = im; %backup
im = im2double(im);
im = rgb2gray(im);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(im);

% --- Executes on button press in fils.
function fils_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to fils (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global im3 im4
[path,user_conce] = imgetfile();
if user_conce
    sprintf('error');
    return
end
im3=imread(path);
im4 = im3; %backup
im3 = im2double(im3);
im3 = rgb2gray(im3);
axes(handles.axes3);
imshow(im3);

% --- Executes on button press in tester.
function tester_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to tester (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

Comment: The error occurs in `pere_Callback` procedure, but you show the code of `fils_Callback`.

Comment: the code has been edited

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have overwritten your `handles` structure.

Comment: i'm a beginner in matlab i don't know what do u mean

Comment: @excaza any solution ?

Comment: what @excaza means is that `handles` is normally a struct and you can normally access a field such as `handles.axes1`. The fact that matlab is telling you that `handles` is not a struct means that you've overwritten it (i.e. redefined it) to be a non-struct. Use the find feature to locate instances of `handles`, and see if you've overwritten it.

Comment: You can set breakpoint on `axes(handles.axes1);` row and check `handles.axes1` variable in Matlab viewer.